TCL lrange command creating arrays for things in quotes
I have following simplified code:
set getevent [exec "show running-config | section UPDATESCRIPTS"]
set geteventsplit [split $getevent "\n"]
foreach entry $geteventsplit {
    if {[llength $entry] > 1} {
        lappend finalconfig1 [lrange $entry 0 end]
        lappend finalconfig2 $entry
    }
}
puts "Output1:"
puts $finalconfig1
puts "Output2:"
puts $finalconfig2

So the data that i get back from the first line looks like this:
event manager applet UPDATESCRIPTS
 event timer cron cron-entry "30 1 * * *"
 action 001 cli command "enable"
 action 002 cli command "set updatescripts"

The output of the running script looks like this:
Output1:
{event manager applet UPDATESCRIPTS} {event timer cron cron-entry {30 1 * * *}} {action 001 cli command enable} {action 002 cli command {set updatescripts}}
Output2:
{event manager applet UPDATESCRIPTS
} { event timer cron cron-entry "30 1 * * *"
} { action 001 cli command "enable"
} { action 002 cli command "set updatescripts"
}

Now the problem that i have is that i want to retain the quotation marks. So the output1 takes originally this line:
event timer cron cron-entry "30 1 * * *"

and converts it to this:
event timer cron cron-entry {30 1 * * *}

Question: how can i retain the quotation marks in the lrange command?

Even though Tcl doesn't have strict datatypes, lrange will do a string-to-list conversion to the $entry variable.
You can't preserve the double quotes with lrange.
You're already preserving the double quotes with the $finalconfig2 variable.   Why do you want to use lrange ?

the $finalconfig2 is just to show what i want in the end. basically i am using the lrange command to get rid of the leading spaces and the return at the end of a line.

OK i could get a workaround going by counting the number of digits and then just use the string range command that preserves the quotations in the line...

To get rid of leading spaces, use string trimleft $orig_string.
To get rid of traiing spaces, use string trimright $orig_string.
To get rid of both leading and trailing spaces, use string trim $orig_string

Are you keeping the text of the line or a list of the words in the line? They're different things! The lrange command does not retain the one-word parts; you use it when you're interested in the list of words in the line only.
Also, you are totally relying on the output from that subprocess having the same interpretation of word as Tcl. That's not generally recommended even if you can get away with it. There are other ways of getting "the list of words in a record" that may be better for your use cases.
